# How to dynamically fill components with content

Tags: angular, typescript, decorator

I need your help. I have four different components

1. content.component - the component that we will fill with unique content and it will display this unique content
2. show-components.component - a component that will show child components and in which we will fill data from our content.component.
3. profile.component - in this component, the content will be displayed and changed, which we will fill with our data from our content.component
4. page.component - a component that will also be filled with unique content

Now I am getting the following error - `Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'nativeElement') at ProfileComponent.ngAfterViewInit` and I don't know how to fix it. Please help me to fix the code and can you please show me how to use my content-component as unique, not only in one component, but in several. Thanks for understanding

content.component.ts

```
import { Component, ElementRef, Host, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { ProfileComponent } from '../profile/profile.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'content'
  template: '<ng-content></ng-content>'
})

export class ContentComponent {

   @Input() title: string;
   @Input() isDone: boolean = false;

   public element: ElementRef;

   constructor(
      @Host() private profile: ProfileComponent,
      private elementRef: ElementRef
   ){
      this.element = elementRef;
      profile.pages.push(this);
      if(profile.activePageInd == -1){
        profile.activePageInd = 0;
      }
   }
}
```

profile.component.ts

```
import {
   Component, ContentChild,
   ElementRef, Renderer2,
   TemplateRef, ViewChild
} from '@angular/core';
import { ContentComponent } from '../content/content.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'profile',
  templateUrl: './profile.component.html',
})

export class ProfileComponent implements AfterViewInit {

  @ContentChild("executorHeader") executorHeader: TemplateRef<void>;
  @ContentChild("executorDescription") executorDescription: TemplateRef<void>;

  @ViewChild('contentContainer') contentContainer: ElementRef<HTMLElement>;

  pages: ContentComponent[] = [];
  private activePageInd : number = -1;

  public get activePageInd() : number {
    return this.activePageInd;
  }

  public set activePageInd(v : number) {
    this.activePageInd = v;
    if (v >= 0 && this.contentContainer) {
     if (this.contentContainer.nativeElement.innerHTML != '') {
      this.contentContainer.nativeElement.innerHTML = '';
     }
     this.renderer.appendChild(
      this.contentContainer.nativeElement,
      this.activePage?.elementRef.nativeElement
     )
    }
  }

  get activePage(): ContentComponent | null {
   return this.activePageInd == -1 ? null : this.pages[this.activePageInd];
  }

  constructor(private renderer: Renderer2) {}

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
   this.renderer.appendChild(
    this.contentContainer.nativeElement,
    this.activePage?.elementRef.nativeElement)
  }

  go(a = 0) {
   this.activePageInd+=a;
  }
}
```

profile.component.html

```
<div *ngIf="activePage">
 <div> {{activePage.title}} </div>
 <div #contentContainer> </div>
</div>
<button (click)="go()">foo</button>
<button (click)="go(1)">go 1</button>
<button (click)="go(-1)">go -1</button>
```

show.executors.component

```
<profile>
  <ng-template #executorHeader> Process header </ng-template>
  <ng-template #executorDescription> Description </ng-template>
  <profile>
   <content [title]="'HEllo 1'"> One </content>
   <content [title]="'HEllo 2'"> Two </content>
   <content [title]="'HEllo 3'"> Three </content>
  <profile>
<profile>
```

page.component - empty component

Comment: It feels like you're trying to do distinctly "un-Angular" things here. Is there any reason you're not using a service or state management with a container/presenter architecture?

Comment: Can you please show an example of how this can be done? Thank you)